# Using Wait By Attribute with Salesforce Entry Data ignoring time

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

My client wants to send SMS to campaigns in Salesforce. The send creates a Task, which is later updated in the journey with a status of SMS Delivered or not.

A campaign send can be created on a Friday to be delivered after 2pm the next Monday (or any working hour decided by the agent). This is done by setting the due date and time while creating the SMS send in Salesforce.

So I am using Salesforce as the entry source (Task object) and a Wait by Attribute that should hold the SMS send until the due date:

[image].

Yesterday in the afternoon I scheduled a send for today at 9AM, but the SMS was sent at midnight so it ignored the time. In the Data Extension related to the journey it shows that:

[image]

We're migrating the SMS sends from another system and the scheduling works there.

So my question is if it could be an issue with how Marketing Cloud reads dates from Sales Cloud or if it's some limitation with Wait by Attribute activity? Or something else that I am missing.

Edit: one possibility is that the problem comes from Due Date in Tasks being a Date format, not a Date/Time. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: FYI, Server time for SFMC is in CST. Date and time information synchronized from the Sales Cloud to the Marketing Cloud change from the specified Sales Cloud time zone to CST in Marketing Cloud. For example, a birthday stored as 09/29/2016 00:00 AM in the Sales Cloud in GMT changes to 09/28/2016 07:00 PM in the Marketing Cloud. Reference
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_data_integration_for_your_account_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5

Comment: I think your last suggestion might be the explanation. You're probably working with a Date formatted field, where the timestamp is defaulting to 00:00 (hours:minutes). Marketing Cloud does not differentiate between the two, so you could try a custom field with datetime format, which is e.g. calculated as ActivityDate + 9hours? Maybe it's worth a try!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Jonas Lamberty the problem was indeed the Date formatted field. I created a custom field using the **Date/Time** format in Sales Cloud and now the time is passing through as well.